# How to iterate through an API response containing a JSON array in Angular2

Tags: angular

This is probably an easy answer, but I already spent days trying to figure it out, without any success.

An HTTP GET returns this body response:

```
{"members":[{"id":1484,"organization_id":3},{"id":1777,"organization_id":3},{"id":2214,"organization_id":3},{"id":2261,"organization_id":3}]}
```

I try to iterate trough it in Angular2:

```
getMembers() {
    this.http.get('http://server/user/members')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.members = data.members
    );
}
```

How can I loop through members and read their property?
The html template can do it perfectly well:

```
<li *ngFor="let m of session.members">
{{m.id}}
</li>
```

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is. Please check my answer and add a comment if you want something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getMembers() {
    this.http.get('http://server/user/members')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.members = data.members;
            this.members.forEach(m => console.log(m.id));
        });
    );
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel stupid now. Thanks a lot Günter for your swift and clear answer. Actually I tried the forEach function in a wrong way and I abandoned it because of that.

Comment: No need to feel stupid. The brain sometimes gets a bit lost when experimenting with new stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over it in template, try:

```
<li *ngFor="#m of session.members | async">
   {{m.id}}
</li>
```